# Some artifacts download failing for under a repo in JFrog's Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I am not able to download specific artifacts(jar) from the JFrog's Artifactory. The download gets stuck at a specific percentage and ultimately fails. The artifact is **com.X.pluginY**(let's say) under the repo "libs-release-local" and the version **[1.1.100, 1.1.244]** is not able to get downloaded whereas the version before 1.1.100 and after 1.1.244 are able to download. Also, the artifacts **com.X.pluginZ** and others are getting downloaded from the same repo "libs-release-local".

I have checked access.log, request.log, and artifactory.log everything is good.

Strangely from some other network, we are able to download those artifacts which are not getting downloaded from the browser and the CI server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Strangely from some other network

That means it is a network issue: do check what is between your Artifactory server and your CI server (typically an [appliance like f5](https://www.f5.com/products) or a reverse proxy provided for instance by [NGiNX](https://www.nginx.com/))
You need to check the logs of those intermediate network points, not Artifactory.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I have been using the same CI and Arifactory from months now without any changes. The CI is able to download all the other artifacts now also but there are some issue only with com.X.pluginY[1.1.100, 1.1.244]

Comment: @ShubhamChoudhary Yes, hence the suggestion of checking the logs of other intermediate nodes, since the logs from Artifactory don't reveal any clues.